# How to upload files from EKS to S3 bucket without creating IAM user?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-eks

I have a pod deployed in Kubernetes environment and created service account to access my S3 bucket with full access. I want to upload my logs to s3 bucket.

```
module.exports.uploadFile = () => {
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'../logger/MyLogFile.log'))
const params = {
    Bucket: 'MYBUCKETNAME',
    Key: 'MyLogFile.log',
    Body: fileContent
};

s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        logger.error('file upload error')
        throw err;
    }
    logger.info(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
})}
```

This is the error I am getting...

> Error [CredentialsError]: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
> at Timeout.connectTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:69:15)
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
> code: 'CredentialsError',
> time: 2021-12-09T10:43:29.712Z,
> retryable: true,
> originalError: {
> message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
> code: 'CredentialsError',
> time: 2021-12-09T10:43:29.705Z,
> retryable: true,
> originalError: {
> message: 'EC2 Metadata roleName request returned error',
> code: 'TimeoutError',
> time: 2021-12-09T10:43:29.705Z,
> retryable: true,
> originalError: {
> message: 'Socket timed out without establishing a connection',
> code: 'TimeoutError',
> time: 2021-12-09T10:43:29.705Z,
> retryable: true
> }
> }
> }
> }

Comment: If you don't want to use IAM user, you can use [Programmatic access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html) This [article](https://tipsfordev.com/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-aws3-with-nodejs) describe such approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a service Account from EKS side to my application resolved the problem.

After creating the service account my file changes will be

1.) aws.yml

> serviceAccount:
> enabled: true
> name: MY_SERVICE_ACC_NAME

2.) my AWS.S3 object creation will not have any changes

```
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

Now the AWS.S3 object will be filled with mandatory parameters automatically.